# How to know form is saved first time in dynamics crm

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to `fire some actions` after `form is saved` only `first time` using javascript. Not in every time when form will save.

Please suggest if there is some event or other solution .

Comment: You should consider performing this actions in a Workflow registered on Create. Otherwise you'll have to use a hack filling a hidden field to transport the state. If you can perform your actions **before** the Save Event is executed, you could check if the Form State is *Create* (`getFormType() == 1`). If you need to perform complex actions, you should consider creating a server-side Plugin.

Comment: Hi filburt.Thanx for reply that is workflow is the way for that.but I want to hide/show one button put in webresourse and that is put on crm contact form. please suggest me if any other way.

Comment: In that case you will need an attribute to carry the state *saved_first_time* which you can set to `false` when your button action succeeded.

Comment: yes i can do that thax..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a form level variable, `hasBeenSaved`, defaulting it to false.  In your onSave Event, you can check to see if it is false, (this is the first time the form is being saved) then set it to true.